# Calculate cost for each month SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, date, group-by, sum

I need to calculate the cost for each project for each month, the project consists of tasks. I have an employee table, tasks table and project table. But I don't know how to calculate the cost for a project each month, so far I have this:

```
SELECT 
    P.PROJECT_NAME, 
    SUM(T.HOURS_WORKED * E.HOURLY_RATE) COST
FROM 
    PROJECT P,
    TASKS T,
    EMPLOYEE E
WHERE 
    E.EMPLOYEE_ID = T.EMPLOYEE_ID
    AND P.PROJECT_ID = T.PROJECT_ID
GROUP BY P.PROJECT_NAME;
```

but that doesn't work out how much is charged for a project each month,it just works out the overall cost by calculating the hours worked by the employees by the employee hourly rate. In the task table I do have a date_worked column which displays the day,month and year but I don't know if that needs to be used or not.

Comment: update your question and add  your table schema.  you should have a date column..

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need group your query by the month when the task was performed.

Also you would better use JOINs.

```
SELECT 
    P.PROJECT_NAME, 
    TRUNC(T.DATE_WORKED, 'month') MONTH,
    SUM(T.HOURS_WORKED * E.HOURLY_RATE) COST
FROM 
    TASKS T
    INNER JOIN PROJECT P ON P.PROJECT_ID = T.PROJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON E.EMPLOYEE_ID = T.EMPLOYEE_ID
GROUP BY P.PROJECT_NAME, TRUNC(T.DATE_WORKED, 'month');
```

Comment: Is there anyway I could show all months, rather than only the months a task was performed or not?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you a date column date_work for each work rec you could use

```
    SELECT P.PROJECT_NAME
            , to_char(date_work, 'YYYY-MM')
            , SUM(T.HOURS_WORKED * E.HOURLY_RATE) COST
    FROM PROJECT P, TASKS T, EMPLOYEE E
    WHERE E.EMPLOYEE_ID = T.EMPLOYEE_ID
    AND P.PROJECT_ID = T.PROJECT_ID
    GROUP BY P.PROJECT_NAME,  to_char(date_work, 'YYYY-MM');
```

and you should not use old implicit join sintax but use explicit join sintax

```
    SELECT P.PROJECT_NAME
            , to_char(date_work, 'YYYY-MM')
            , SUM(T.HOURS_WORKED * E.HOURLY_RATE) COST
    FROM PROJECT P
    INNER JOIN TASKS T ON P.PROJECT_ID = T.PROJECT_ID
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE E ON  E.EMPLOYEE_ID = T.EMPLOYEE_ID
    GROUP BY P.PROJECT_NAME,  to_char(date_work, 'YYYY-MM');
```